# SQL Shell (psql) don't run any commands on Windows

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm new to **postgreSQL**, It crashes often suddenly for no reason and does not execute any commands ( I'm using **;**)
and the only solution is to close the window and reopen it.

[image: Screenshot for commands and the no-result]

What's the reason?

Comment: Do not post images for textual information, see here [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Copy and paste from the terminal and update to your question.  The `'` in the prompt indicates you left a string unquoted, that is why the command is not executed.

Comment: @Adrian but in this case, the image might have helped, as in pasting text the offending character might have been trimmed off in formatting.

Comment: @jjanes, that is not the case: `test(5432)=# select 'some_fld
test'# `.

Comment: I meant manual formatting, not automatically by stackoverflow.  I know I often trim off the extra prompts lines (or line numbering, if using a terminal that has it), as they interrupt the flow of the part I consider important.